# Who is the winner?

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I've made the code, but I can't seem to find why the output doesn't show.

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSGFz.png)

Problem 2: Who is the winner? (Level 2)

> • Problem description
>   Alice and Bob are playing a game. Both of them write down an integer number. If the sum of two integers is a square of an integer, Alice wins the game. If the reversed number of the sum is a square of an integer, Bob wins. If neither of them wins, or both of them win, it is a tie.
>
> For example, Alice wrote an 8, Bob wrote a 10. 18 is not a square of any integer. But 81 is a square of 9. So Bob is the winner.
>   Write a program to take two integers numbers and output the winner of the game.
>
> • Input & output requirements
>
> Input two positive integer numbers. The output should follow the format as shown in sample results:
>
> Sample 1

```
8 10
Bobs wins
```

> Sample 2

```
2 2
Tie
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(int numOne, int numTwo)
{
  int rev;
  rev = numTwo*10 + numOne;

  return rev;
}

int issquare(int num)
{
  int i, valid;
  valid = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    if((i*i) == num)
    {
      valid = 1;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}
int main()
{
  int num1, num2, normal, rev, alice, bob;
  scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
  printf("%d %d", num1, num2);
  rev = reverse(num1, num2);
  normal = num1*10 + num2;
  bob = issquare(normal);
  alice = issquare(rev);
  if(bob==1)
  {
    if(alice==1)
    {
      printf("Tie");
    }
  }
  if(bob==1)
  {
    if(alice==0)
    {
      printf("Bob wins.");
    }
  }
  if(alice==1)
  {
    if(bob==0)
    {
      printf("Alice wins.");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your code. That usually helps.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Think. Improve the code to get no warnings. **Use the debugger `gdb`**. Think. Repeat till you are satisfied. *Fix-my-code* and *do-my-homework* questions are *off-topic* here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this part of an ongoing contest?

Comment: Whoops sorry for the trouble. Thanks for the advise guys.

Comment: Is there a section that can teach me how to use StackOverflow properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be the `bob == 0` and `alice == 0` case. Put an print stamement in the else statement you will know why. Your execution is making that case somehow.

Also in `issquare` you should have the loop like this

`for(i = 0; i <= num; i++)` because for numbers like `1` it would fail.

Also there is a flaw in your logic. You should form the number

`8 10` you should check `81` and `18`. But in your case you don't do this.(You check `90` and `108`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int reverse(int num)
{
  int rev=0,inter = 0;
  while(num){ 
    inter = rev*10;
    if( inter/10 != rev){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    rev=inter+num%10;
    num/=10;
  }
  return rev;
}

int issquare(int num)
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++){
    long long ii = i;
    long long mul  = ii*ii;
    if( ii!= 0 &&  mul/ii != ii){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Overflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(mul == num)
      return 1;
    else if(mul > num){
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int num1, num2, normal, rev, alice, bob;
  if( scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2)!= 2){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  printf("%d %d", num1, num2);
  rev = reverse(num1+num2);
  normal = num1+ num2;
  bob = issquare(rev);
  alice = issquare(normal);
  if(bob==alice)
    printf("Tie"); 
  else if(bob > alice)
      printf("Bob wins.");
  else 
    printf("Alice wins.");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you calculate `normal` is not correct.

```
normal=num1+num2;
```

And function you write for `reverse` is also not correct.

```
int reverse(int num1,int num2)
{
   int sum=num1+num2;
   int ans=0;
   while(sum>0)
   {
      ans =ans*10 +(sum%10);
      sum/=10;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

And you also not checking for condition where **both lose**.
Add that condition as well.

Comment: Hello yajiv, thanks for the reply.